# Unable to import a module thats already installed

Tags: python, importerror

I did `pip freeze` and the module was there in the list. Yet when I try to import it, getting the error below:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
```

The virtual environment is activated too.
I saw another thread regarding this same issue but it was too technical for me to understand.

What do I do now? I am a newbie to linux btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using anaconda for virtual environment, it is possible that the pip file running your `pip freeze` command does not point to the pip executable within the environment. You can verify this by running `which pip`. If the resultant path does not contain your virtual environment name in it, it is likely that the issue is what I just mentioned above. The solution to that is to install pip inside your conda environment.

Ensure that you run the following commands after activating your conda environment.

```
conda install pip
```

now install whatever package you want using the `pip install <package_name>`